# How to embed and play on same page like popup?

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I'm learning web development with Drupal 7.

I can embed [youtube](http://www.youtube.com) video using [CKEditor](https://www.google.com.pk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiykP-ohePSAhVGkRQKHTPNAh0QFggXMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.drupal.org%2Fproject%2Fckeditor&usg=AFQjCNHBwzmHVMwYX8r8g7KtJw9LaGdRCg&sig2=ZV9ADm9gsZZgByt-oLLIyQ&bvm=bv.149760088,d.bGs) on a node. I like to play embedded video looks like on [YIFY](https://yts.ag/movie/silence-2016) and [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2034800/?ref_=nv_sr_1) as popup/overlay. It means when I click on play button it will open as popup on the same page and on click outside the youtube player or whatever, it will stop and display nodes' content.

How this can be possible, JS/JQuery will be used? If yes then how and please suggest me the other ways as well.

Comment: Which ***other*** ways?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this functionality by using something like [colorbox](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox). This will allow you to open videos in popup. Since you've just started learning drupal, I would recommend that you thoroughly follow [documentation for this module](https://www.drupal.org/node/1971564).

Another alternative is using modules [video_embed_field](https://www.drupal.org/project/video_embed_field) along with colorbox. This will allow you to use colorbox as field formatter.